# Copying postgres data base with links / ref ids

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-copy

Trying to extract a csv of a db table

Using...
COPY sale_order TO '/tmp/salesorder.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

I get..

- id  - partner_id
- 1   - 45
- 2   - 55

"partner_id" is references another table "contacts" as id, where I want "name"

Can I ref the partner_id to output

- id  - name
- 1   -Fred Blogs
- 2   -John Smith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to [copy from a query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html):

```
copy (
    select so.id, p.name
    from
        sale_order so
        inner join
        partner p on p.id = so.partner_id
) to '/tmp/salesorder.csv' delimiter ',' csv header;
```

Comment: - sorry I was a tad wrong with the information I supplied "partner_id" is the id of the table "contacts"

Comment: Many thanks Clodoaldo, a few tweaks and I was on a roll